# Kafka-Streaming: How to collect pairs of messages and write to a new topic

Tags: java, lambda, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

This is a beginner's question to kafka-streaming.

How would you collect pairs of messages using the java kafka-streaming library and write them to a new output topic?

I was thinking about something like this:

```
private void accumulateTwo(KStream<String, String> messages) {
    Optional<String> accumulator = Optional.empty();
    messages.mapValues(value -> {
        if (accumulator.isPresent()) {
            String tmp = accumulator.get();
            accumulator = Optional.empty();
            return Optional.of(new Tuple<>(tmp, value));
        }
        else {
            accumulator = Optional.of(value);
            return Optional.empty();
        }
    }).filter((key, value) -> value.isPresent()).to("pairs");
```

Yet this will not work, since variables in Java Lambda expressions must be final.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using mapValues() (that is a stateless operation)` might result in data loss! You should use a transform() with state store instead!

Comment: Cf https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, three additional steps are necessary:

1. The `Transformer` must explicitly store its state within a state store. It will get a reference to the state store from the `ProcessorContext`, which it is getting passed in the `init` method.
2. The state store must be registered with the `StreamsBuilder`
3. The name of the state store must be passed within the `transform` method.

In this example it is sufficient to store the last message we have seen. We are using a `KeyValueStore` for this which will have exactly zero or one entry at each point in time.

```
public class PairTransformerSupplier<K,V> implements TransformerSupplier<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V,V>>> {

    private String storeName;

    public PairTransformerSupplier(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    @Override
    public Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>>> get() {
        return new PairTransformer<>(storeName);
    }
}


public class PairTransformer<K,V> implements Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>>> {
    private ProcessorContext context;
    private String storeName;
    private KeyValueStore<Integer, V> stateStore;

    public PairTransformer(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        stateStore = (KeyValueStore<Integer, V>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>> transform(K key, V value) {
        // 1. Update the store to remember the last message seen. 
        if (stateStore.get(1) == null) {
            stateStore.put(1, value); return null;
        }
        KeyValue<K, Pair<V,V>> result = KeyValue.pair(key, new Pair<>(stateStore.get(1), value));
        stateStore.put(1, null);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() { }

}


public KStream<String, String> sampleStream(StreamsBuilder builder) {
    KStream<String, String> messages = builder.stream(inputTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
    // 2. Create the state store and register it with the streams builder. 
    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier store = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(stateStoreName);
    StoreBuilder storeBuilder = new KeyValueStoreBuilder<>(
            store,
            new Serdes.IntegerSerde(),
            new Serdes.StringSerde(),
            Time.SYSTEM
    );
    builder.addStateStore(storeBuilder);
    transformToPairs(messages);
    return messages;
}

private void transformToPairs(KStream<String, String> messages) {
    // 3. reference the name of the state store when calling transform(...)
    KStream<String, Pair<String, String>> pairs = messages.transform(
            new PairTransformerSupplier<>(),
            stateStoreName
    );
    KStream<String, Pair<String, String>> filtered = pairs.filter((key, value) -> value != null);
    KStream<String, String> serialized = filtered.mapValues(Pair::toString);
    serialized.to(outputTopic);
}
```

Changes to the state store can be watched using the console consumer:

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer --topic <changelog-topic-name> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Full source code here: https://github.com/1123/spring-kafka-stream-with-state-store

## Original Answer:

The JavaDoc of the `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper` interface states that it is for stateless record-by-record transformations, and that the `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer` interface, on the other hand, is

> for stateful mapping of an input record to zero, one, or multiple new output records.

Therefore I guess the `Transformer` interface is the appropriate choice for collecting pairs of messages. This may only be of relevance in case of failure and restart of streaming applications, such that they can recover the state from Kafka.

Hence, here is another solution based upon the `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Transformer` interface:

```
class PairTransformerSupplier<K,V> implements TransformerSupplier<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V,V>>> {

    @Override
    public Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>>> get() {
        return new PairTransformer<>();
    }
}

public class PairTransformer<K,V> implements Transformer<K, V, KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>>> {
    private V left;

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        left = null;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>> transform(K key, V value) {
        if (left == null) { left = value; return null; }
        KeyValue<K, Pair<V,V>> result = KeyValue.pair(key, new Pair<>(left, value));
        left = null;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<K, Pair<V, V>> punctuate(long timestamp) {
        return null;
    }

    public void close() { }

}
```

The PairTransformerSupplier is then used as follows:

```
private void accumulateTwo(KStream<String, String> messages) {
    messages.transform(new PairTransformerSupplier<>())
            .filter((key, value) -> value != null)
            .mapValues(Pair::toString)
            .to("pairs");
}
```

Trying out both solutions within a single process on a topic with a single partition yields, however, the exact same results. I have not tried with a topic with multiple partitions and multiple stream consumers.

Comment: `transform()` is only stateful if you attach and use a state. Your example works stateless and might loose data in case of failure.

Comment: Cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax: Thanks for the feedback and the link. Always good to learn more.

Comment: The answer has been updated to setup a state store and use it in the transform method.

Comment: It doesn't seem that you *use* the state in your updated answer... Thus, it's still not fault-tolerant.

Comment: Thanks again. Updated the answer, so that it is now hopefully correct. At least one can watch changes to the topic on Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to write an accumulator class

```
class Accumulator implements ValueMapper<String, Optional<Tuple<String>>> {
    private String key;

    public Optional<Tuple<String>> get(String item) {
        if (key == null) {
            key = item;
            return Optional.empty();
        }
        Optional<Tuple<String>> result = Optional.of(new Tuple<>(key, item));
        key = null;
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then process with

```
messages.mapValues(new Accumulator())
        .filter(Optional::isPresent) // I don't think your filter is correct
        .to("pairs");
```

Comment: I could not get it to work by implementing the `Function` interface. Instead I had to implement `org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper`. But then it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: If you found a working solution that is not yet covered in an existing answer, please create a new answer so that other readers of this question don't have to hunt in the comment sections to find a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelG.Noll this answer has now been adjusted to use the ValueMapper. So it is now covered. Also I added an answer based on the Transformer interface below.

Comment: @user152468 Using `mapValues()` (that is a stateless operation)` might result in data loss! You should use a `transform()` with state store instead!

Comment: cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Thanks for explanation & link. Haven't really done KStream processing myself and the answer is pretty much for a normal Java 8 stream.

Comment: To clarify what Matthias J. Sax wrote: "Using mapValues() (that is a stateless operation)` might result in data loss!"  This is meant for when mapValues() is used as suggested in the answer, i.e. mapValues() by itself does not lose data of course.  But if you use mapValues (a stateless function) to implement a stateful operation like in the suggested answer, then you will run into problems.